# Чтение строк из файла и добавление в массив/коллекцию

Tags: java, массивы, файлы, коллекции

необходимо файл со списком дат добавить в массив/коллекцию. каждая дата написана с новой строки. и соответственно каждая дата должна быть отдельным элементом массива. и после, вывести даты с определенным временем на экран и в конце написать кол-во всех дат и кол-во выписанных дат.

вопрос: как добавить информацию из файла в коллекцию?

пример строк из файла:

01 03 2007 09 36 146.102.174.177 GET

01 03 2007 12 52 146.102.174.177 GET

Есть конец кода. Как его правильно начать/отредактировать, подскажите, пожалуйста

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet();
```

// добавление строк из файла в hashset

```
for (String str : set) {
        char aChar = str.charAt(12);
        if (aChar == '9') {
            System.out.println(str);

        }
    }
    System.out.println("Strok: " + set.size());
    HashSet<String> set1 = new HashSet();
    for (String str : set) {
        char aChar = str.charAt(1);
        if (aChar == 'а') {
            set1.add(str);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Vypisanyh strok: " + set1.size());
```

Comment: Простите, что значит, даты с определённым временем? В каком формате подаются эти данные о времени?

Comment: @КириллМалышев 09 36 (в первой дате) и 12 52 (во 2-й) это время. мне надо вывести на экран все строки с временем - 9 часов. для этого я и использовал: 

    char aChar = str.charAt(12);
        if (aChar == '9')

В файле более тысячи дат с разным временем

Comment: @КириллМалышев спасибо за ваш ответ. но сейчас появилась проблемка - в коде пишет ошибку в in. и ex. ( in.hasNext() и ex.printStackTrace() ). (Cannot resolve symbol). Не подскажите, как это решить. Код скопировал с вашего ответа.

Comment: Я правил ответ, забыл поменять. Нужно изменить на while(sc.hasNext()){ и e.printStackTrace(); . Если что не работает ещё, пишите. Я код с файлом не тестировал.

Comment: @КириллМалышев Оба кода работают. большое спасибо. только единственное, как при использовании вашего первого кода, так и при использовании вашего второго кода + моей части через charAt, при выводе на экран "Выведено дат: "/"Strok: " число не соответствует реальному кол-ву дат в файле. пишет, что дат 3291, попробовал добавить лимит в сплите и 5, 6 line - число увеличилось до 11140. но в файле 144000 дат. с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Это связан с тем, что вы выбрали для хранения дат HashSet. Как известно, эта структура хранит только уникальные объекты. Соответственно, из 2-х одинаковых дат сохранится только одна. Для того чтобы сохранить все данные, стоит использовать ArrayList. Создайте его вместо HashSet: ArrayList<Date> dateList = new ArrayList(); Поменяйте везде имя set на имя списка. Кстати, из-за лимита на split ничего меняться не должно, его можно вообще убрать.

Comment: Если вас устраивает ответ, примите его, нажав на галочку под его рейтингом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не стоит хранить дату как строку. Ведь для этого в Java есть специальные классы. Можно, например, использовать для хранения даты класс `Date`.

Вот пример:

```
HashSet<Date> set = new HashSet();  // Создаём множество объектов Date
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy HH mm");  // Задаём формат ввода/вывода даты
try {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("filename.txt")); // Инициализируем сканер
    while(sc.hasNext()){  // Читаем, пока читается
        String[] line = sc.nextLine().split(" ", 6);  // Делим строку по пробелу
        Date date = formatter.parse(line[0] + " " + line[1] + " " +
                    line[2] + " " + line[3] + " " + line[4]);  // Парсим дату
        set.add(date);  // Добавляем её в множество
    }
    sc.close();  // Закрываем сканер
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  // Инициализируем консольный сканер
System.out.println("Введите номер часа");
int hours = in.nextInt();  // Номер часа, по которому ищем
int count = 0;  // Счётчик найденных дат
for(Date date: set){  // Проходим по датам
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();  // Создаём объект Calendar
    calendar.setTime(date);  // И передаём туда дату
    if(hours == calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)){  // Если номер часа совпадает
        count++;  // Инкрементируем счётчик
        System.out.print(formatter.format(date));  // И выводим отформатированную дату
    }
}
System.out.println("Выведено дат: " + count);
System.out.println("Всего дат: " + set.size());
```

https://ideone.com/Wdw381

Если всё-таки хотите хранить просто откусывать от строки файла дату и добавлять её в множество, то добавьте этот код:

```
try {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("filename.txt")); // Инициализируем сканер
    while(sc.hasNext()){  // Читаем, пока читается
        String[] line = sc.nextLine().split(" ", 6);  // Делим строку по пробелу
        String date = line[0] + " " + line[1] + " " + line[2] + " " +
                      line[3] + " " + line[4];  // Берём дату
        set.add(date);  // Добавляем её в множество
    }
    sc.close();  // Закрываем сканнер
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```